# extra initialization in new window of a MFC/OpenCV project

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have a computer vision project using OpenCV and MFC for the GUI.
I want to do the following: when i click Button1, i get a new window that displays a video then captures images by clicking on the buttons of that new window.

First, i had an MFC project with only the window that displays the video and it worked fine. Then i created a new project where i made that window comes after clicking on a button. Here is the code that i used to call that window.

```
  void ClassTestDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CDialog ClassTestDlg(IDD_DIALOG_WindowDisplay);
    ClassTestDlg.DoModal();
}
```

After clicking on button1, i can see the new window but the video doesn't display.
The class of the new dialog doesn't contain an "OnInitDialog()" method and i don't know how to write extra initialization in this new class.

I am new to MFC so Help please.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate a CDialog, only a class derived from CDialog.

Your button handler is in class ClassTestDlg, so why are you trying to create another ClassTestDlg? You need something like this:

```
void ClassFirstDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
 ClassSecondDlg dlg2;
 dlg2.DoModal();
}
```